# If $E$ is measurable, then $E=F\cup Z$ s.t $F$ is a $F_\sigma$ set, and $m(Z)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ be [Lebesgue]measurable.

Then $E=F\cup Z$ s.t $F$ is a $F_\sigma$ set, and $m(Z)=0$

Since (outer) measure zero is measurable and $F_\sigma$ set is also measurable, and (finite) union of measurable sets are measurable,

We can conclude : $F\cup Z \subset E.$

I am stucked to prove $F\cup Z \supset E$.

How can I do this?

Or is there any way to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the following equivalence:$E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesuge measurable if and only if for every $\varepsilon >0$, there is a closed subset $F_\varepsilon $ of $E$ such that $m(E\setminus F_\varepsilon)\leq \varepsilon.$ For the proof, see Royden&Fitzpatrick. Although the book proves the case $n=1$, the proof is essentially same.

From this fact, we prove the result. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, by measurability of $E$, there is a closed subset $F_n$ of $E$ such that $m(E\setminus F_n)\leq \frac{1}{n}$. Set $F=\bigcup_{n=1} F_n$. Then by definition, $F$ is $F_\sigma$-set. Set $Z_n = E\setminus F_n$ and let $Z=\bigcap Z_n$. Then by monotonicity, we have $m(Z)\leq m(Z_n)<\frac{1}{n}.$ Since $n$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $Z$ has measure zero.

Then note that 
$$E=(E\setminus Z)\cup Z = F\cup Z,$$
which completes the proof.